# How to set transparent color in Color.parseColor()

Tags: android, android-color

I'm using a third-party library for using tooltips. the tooltip has a method **.setColor()** which uses an integer color value. so I tried doing this:

```
private int toolTipColor = Color.parseColor("##B2000000");
```

I get a run time error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raunak.alarmdemo4/com.raunak.alarmdemo4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

is there any alternative? for setting a transparent color.

Comment: Remove the second `#`, so you are using `#B2000000`. Beyond that, you might want to edit your question and post the entire stack trace, not just one line.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for pointing out my mistake. it was the second '#' causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseColor()` expects a single `#` -- you had two. In your case, it appears that the parser choked on the second `#`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. In addition first two letters aka hexadecimal digits B2 represents the transparency level of the color #000000 which is perfect black. Question for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464912/how-to-detect-swipe-between-views-to-make-path-across-them-in-android-java